Use a string as an object's property name in typescript
Given an object with a type like the one below:
type Variables = {
  _id: string;
  variable1: string;
  variable2: string | null;
  variable3: string | null;
  variable4: string | null;
  variable5: string | null;
}

Is it possible to access one of its properties using bracket notation and a string, without tricking Typescript's type system? Currently I'm doing it (roughly) like this:
const level = 1;
const propertyName = `variable${level}` as unknown as keyof Variables;
const variableAtLevel = instance[propertyName];

Even though I have implemented safeguards so as to not try to access something that doesn't exist, this looks hacky at best, and a potential failure point at worst. Is there a safer way to do it?

Yes, you can do that with an Index Signature on your type.
type Variables = {
  _id: string;
  variable1: string;
  variable2: string | null;
  variable3: string | null;
  variable4: string | null;
  variable5: string | null;
  [x: `variable${number}`]: string | null;
} 
declare const variable: Variables;

const level = 1;
const variableAtLevel = variable[`variable${level}`];

TypeScript Playground

You could re-write your types like so:
type VariableIndex = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
type VariableFields = { [Key in `variable${VariableIndex}`]?: string; };
type VariableKey = keyof VariableFields;
type Variables = { _id: string; } & VariableFields;

const instance: Variables = {
  _id: 'a',
  variable1: 'b',
  variable2: 'c',
  variable3: 'd',
  variable4: 'e',
  variable5: 'f'
};

const level: VariableIndex = 1;
const propertyName: VariableKey = `variable${level}` as const;
const variableAtLevel: string = instance[propertyName]!;

console.log(variableAtLevel); // Outputs 'b'

